# generating function given weight function

Tags: combinatorics

Let $N$ be the set $\{1, 2, 3, . . . \}$ of positive integers.

Note that every positive integer n has a unique factorization
as $2^lm$, where $l$ is a non-negative integer and $m$ is a positive odd integer. Define a weight function $w$ on $N$ as follows:

$w(n) = l + m$,

where $(l, m)$ is the unique pair of integers as given by the factorization above. Find the generating series $Φ(x)$ of $N$
with respect to this weight function, and express it as a rational function of $x$.

I know the generating function is $x + x^2 + 2x^3 + 2x^4 + 3x^5 + 3x^6 ...$
but how can i express this as a rational function?

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Notice that the coefficients of $x^{2n-1}$ and $x^{2n}$ are always $n$ for $n\ge 1$. (This isn’t hard to prove.) Thus, your power series is

$$\sum_{n\ge 1}nx^{2n-1}+\sum_{n\ge 1}nx^{2n}=\sum_{n\ge 0}(n+1)x^{2n+1}+\sum_{n\ge 1}nx^{2n}=x\sum_{n\ge 0}(n+1)x^{2n}+\sum_{n\ge 1}nx^{2n}\;.$$

Can you finish it from there?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Remember that $$\frac{1}{1-x}= 1 + x + x^2 + \cdots .$$ Let $p$ denote your generating function. What is $1+p(x)-(1-x)^{-1}$?